# We would like to draw a line at maximum value on a chart

Tags: teechart

We are using FastReport tool for reporting.
On this report there is a teechart where we would like to draw a line at maximum value of some bar charts.

[image: Sample of a chart with line at maximum]

We have tried to solve the problem with adding new series but the problem is that the line doesn't start at x = 0.
How can we achieve that there would be a line at maximum values starting at x = 0 (right after y axis).

[Example with series, not starting at x=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzpVO.png)

Example of code for drawing the line:

```
void __fastcall TFTedPoro::cxButton2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    double XMin, XMax, YVal;
    frxReport1->LoadFromFile("porocilo.fr3");

    TfrxChartView *cv;
    cv = (TfrxChartView *)frxReport1->FindObject("Chart1");
    if (cv != NULL)
    {
        cv->Chart->Series[0]->Marks->Visible = false;
        cv->Chart->Series[1]->Marks->Visible = false;
        cv->Chart->Series[2]->Marks->Visible = false;
        cv->Chart->Series[3]->Marks->Visible = false;
        cv->Chart->Series[4]->Marks->Visible = false;
        cv->Chart->Series[5]->Marks->Visible = false;
        cv->Chart->Series[6]->Marks->Visible = false;

        if (max_vred >= 350)
        {
            cv->Chart->LeftAxis->Maximum = max_vred;
        }
    }

    XMin = cv->Chart->Series[0]->XValues->MinValue;
    XMax = cv->Chart->Series[0]->XValues->MaxValue;
    YVal = cv->Chart->Series[0]->YValues->MaxValue;

    for (int i = 1; i < cv->Chart->SeriesCount()-1;i++)
    {
        XMin = Min(XMin, cv->Chart->Series[i]->XValues->MinValue);
        XMax = Max(XMax, cv->Chart->Series[i]->XValues->MaxValue);
        YVal = Max(YVal, cv->Chart->Series[i]->YValues->MaxValue);
    }
    cv->Chart->Series[8]->AddXY(XMin-1, YVal);
    cv->Chart->Series[8]->AddXY(XMax+1, YVal);
    cv->Chart->Axes->Bottom->SetMinMax(XMin-0.5, XMax+0.5);

    frxReport1->ShowReport(true);
}
```

The result looks like this:
[Chart with code on button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOV9y.png)

Comment: In the image I see a red horizontal line at y=350. I'm not sure to understand what's the problem with it. The red line seems to start right after the left y axis.

Comment: This is what we would like to achieve, but we can't. If we add series for a line, line soesn't start at x = 0 - see attached image above

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TColorLineTool` as in the example in the Features Demo:

[image: ColorLine]

The Features Demo is shipped with [TeeChart VCL evaluation version](https://www.steema.com/downloads/vcl):

**Update:**

If you don't have access to the Chart Tools, another approach would be using a `TLineSeries` with two values.
Note you can set a first `XValue` smaller to the smallest `XValue` in your other series, and a second `XValue` bigger than the biggest `XValue` in your other series. Then, you can manually set the bottom axis `Minimum` and `Maximum` (ie through `SetMinMax(min, max)` function) to only fit the points in your original series.

Here it is a simple example:

```
uses Series, Math;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
    XMin, XMax, YVal: double;
begin
  for i:=0 to 7 do
  begin
    with Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries do
    begin
      Marks.Visible:=false;
      FillSampleValues();
    end;
  end;

  XMin:=Chart1[0].XValues.MinValue;
  XMax:=Chart1[0].XValues.MaxValue;
  YVal:=Chart1[0].YValues.MaxValue;
  for i:=1 to Chart1.SeriesCount-1 do
  begin
    XMin:=Min(XMin, Chart1[i].XValues.MinValue);
    XMax:=Max(XMax, Chart1[i].XValues.MaxValue);
    YVal:=Max(YVal, Chart1[i].YValues.MaxValue);
  end;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries) as TLineSeries do
  begin
    AddXY(XMin-1, YVal);
    AddXY(XMax+1, YVal);
  end;

  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(XMin-0.5, XMax+0.5);
end;
```

This is how the example above looks for me here:

[image: Bars]

A third alternative would be to manually draw an horizontal line at `OnAfterDraw`. Ie:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var Ythreshold: Double;
    tmpY: Integer;
begin
  Ythreshold:=Chart1[0].YValues.MaxValue;
  tmpY:=Chart1.Axes.Left.CalcPosValue(Ythreshold);
  Chart1.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clRed;
  Chart1.Canvas.Line(Chart1.Axes.Bottom.IStartPos, tmpY, Chart1.Axes.Bottom.IEndPos, tmpY);
end;
```

Comment: We are using TeeChart with Fast report 4.15. We couldn't find TColorLineTool in this release. We tried to use LineVIew instead, but the problem is that the maximum value of x axes is dynamically generated, so the position of a line is not fixed.

Comment: Yes I have seen, but I don't understand how can I implement your solution with TLineSeries. I am not sure where can I set first and second XValue and I also don't how to set Minimum and Maximum.

Comment: You have to find the minimum and maximum XValue of the current series (say XMin and XMax), add two values to the `TLineSeries` (`AddXY(XMin-1, YVal)` and `AddXY(XMax+1, YVal)`) and set the Bottom axis range (`Chart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(XMin, XMax);`)

Comment: If we call cv->Chart->Series[6]->MaxXValue, we always get 0 value. The same with MinXValue.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I have translated your example to C++ but the Min and Max values are always 0. Please check my code above. I have also attached image of a chart with this code implemented.

Comment: Can you please try it without FastReports? This way we will be closer to a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I have successfuly tested it directly in TeeChart, but on FastReport still doesn't work :(

Comment: Being embedded into FastReports, probably the chart can't be drawn internally to initialize those variables. Since you have another mean to access the data, you could calculate `XMin`, `XMax` and `YMax` directly from the data instead of taking `XValues.MinValue` / `XValues.MaxValue` / `YValues.MaxValue` from the series.

Comment: I have tried also that, but the x-position of series which should draw a line at maximum is always the same no metter what values I give.

Comment: I have also tried with your third method, but it seems that TeeChart doesn't have CalPosValue function.

Comment: Can't you calculate the XMax value from your data? If you are adding the values to your series without X value, then the X values are 0, 1, 2, 3,...

Comment: `CalcPosValue` is a function that should be accessible at axis level.

Comment: Thank you we have solved the issue.
Here is the code:
  cv->SeriesData->Items[7]->Source2 = "350;350";
  cv->SeriesData->Items[7]->Source3 = "-0.4;8.6";
  cv->Chart->Axes->Bottom->SetMinMax(XMin, XMax);